# How to remove weather indicator for one user?

Tags: indicator

How do I disable the weather indicator in notification area ? I don't want to uninstall it because some other users need it. But, as I already run another weather application, this one is unuseful for my session.

Answer (score 4):

I went to /etc/xdg/autostart and found an "NoDisplay=true" entry in indicator-weather.destkop file. After this key being commented on (with #) the weather indicator was shown in "startup applications" (and menus). So, it can be checked/uncheck by user settings.

Resolved with [your help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46654/how-to-remove-weather-indicator-for-one-user/46667#46667). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not have a fix per se, I have a potential workaround.  I am not sure how many users you are dealing with, but am assuming that we are not talking about hundreds or thousands (please correct me if I am wrong).  In any event, my weather indicator is autostarted from /etc/xdg/autostart.  This is where we will start...

- Open a terminal
- Add a new group, we'll call it
  'weather': `sudo groupadd weather`
- Let's get to where we'll be working:
  `cd /etc/xdg/autostart`
- Find the appropriate .desktop file
  and change the associated group:

  `sudo chown root:weather indicator-weather.desktop`

Note that for this example, we have assigned group ownership to our newly created group, 'weather'.  Also, my .desktop file is named 'indicator-weather.desktop'.  Yours may be different, so please use what is appropriate.

- Now we will want to set the proper
  permissions:

  `sudo chmod g+x,o-x indicator-weather.desktop`
- Next we need to add the users who
  want to use the weather indicator to
  our new 'weather' group:

  `sudo useradd -G {weather} username`

Keep issuing the above command until all of the users who need to use the weather indicator applet have been added to the 'weather' group, obviously leaving yourself out of the group.

As an aside, you can check to ensure that a user is part of the 'weather' group by issuing the following command: `id username`

If all works as planned, the next time you login, you will not see the weather indicator, but when another of your user logs...they should see it.  Hope this works for you.